# Как сделать несколько блоков "Рекомендуемое" на главной Opencart 3.x

Tags: php, opencart, cms

подскажите пожалуйста, на главной есть блок - "Рекомендуемое", как сделать через админку или примерными правками в коде, еще пару таких блоков типо "Найболее покупаемые", "Новые" и тд ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эти модули уже есть в cборке. Они называются `Bestsellers` и `Latest`.

Уно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дуос:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Трэс:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

НО!

Данные модули автоматизированные и отображают товары на основании выборки по своим критериям. Для `Latest` - по дате добавления, для `Bestsellers` - на основании статистики продаж.

Если вы хотите полностью управлять контентом блока, как в случае с модулем `Featured`, то придётся полностью скопировать этот модуть (`Featured` - `Рекомендуемое`) на уровне кода.

Comment: спасибо,действительно можно просто по аналогии Latest все скопировать,только функцию вызова продуктов поменять. а тут не подскажете https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1088045/%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%9d%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8e-%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be ?